# Oracle SQL Extract Year from VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle

Please don't roast me for not being able to figure this out. I'm a beginner with SQL and I've been trying to find a solution and make it work for at least a couple hours in total. I know the date fields should be stored as dates, not varchar2, but I have no control over that.

```
EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM ( TO_DATE ( 'ENTDAT', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ))) = 2018
"ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
```

I feel like I'm close with this, just missing some magic and hoping for an assist here.

Comment: Start with the `TO_DATE` part. Does it work as expected? Try `TO_DATE ( ENTDAT, 'MM/DD/YYYY' )`, without quotes for the column name.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `'ENTDATE'`, otherwise it's a literal string, not a column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'ENTDAT'` is a string literal.

`ENTDAT` (without the quotes) could be a column name.

So if your column name is `ENTDAT` you probably wanted:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM ( TO_DATE ( ENTDAT, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ))) = 2018
```

Comment: You may want to mention that if the error persists after using the column name correctly, then values in `ENTDAT` do not conform to the format specified, in which case the problem is worse than expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel stupid that it was something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is in that format, just use `like`:

```
where enddate like '%2018'
```

Of course, you should be storing a date as a `date`.  Then you can use:

```
where enddate >= date '2018-01-01' and
      enddate < date '2019-01-01'
```